# adding constraint to column using another table's column

Tags: mysql, constraints

So I'm trying to add a constraint from one column in a table using another column's value in a separate table.

I tried:

`ALTER TABLE BOOK_STORES
ADD CONSTRAINT Rep_ID
CHECK(Rep_ID IN (SELECT Rep_ID FROM STORE_REPS));`

These are my two tables:

Store_Reps

`Rep_ID INT(5) (PK), Last VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, First VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, Comm CHAR(1)`

Book_Stores

`Store_ID INT(8), Name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL, Contact VARCHAR(20), Rep_ID(5)`

I'm trying to add the constraint to the book stores rep_id using the store_reps rep_id

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE BOOK_STORES
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (Rep_ID) REFERENCES STORE_REPS(Rep_Id);
```

You can also do this directly in the `create table` statement quite succinctly:

```
create table book_stores (
     . . .
     Rep_Id int references store_reps(rep_id),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's for homework and she asked us to add it after we created the table. That is good to know for the future. Thanks again.